# How to get text from div class using Selenium and find_element() method

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath, css-selectors

I'm trying to get the values ​​inside the div, after finishing a scroll in selenium. The scroll part works correctly, but I can't print the values ​​of the div class.

My code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service


s=Service('D:\enviroments\casino\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
url='https://www.casinoimportaciones.com.uy/accesorios-escola'
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(5)
# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(5)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,-250);")
        time.sleep(10)
        elem2=driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"//div[@class='description']")
        
        print(elem2)
        time.sleep(100)
    else:
        last_height = new_height
```

Output error:

[image: console error]

---

### Update

Update: After fix find_element, he print a list of elements, but no the text:

[image: error]

Comment: You seem to be trying to find element by class name, but you are inputting an XPATH not a class name. Change the line to `elem2=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='description']")`

Comment: Yes, it works, but no print elem2, shows information of session error.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're receiving may be due to you're searching by class name but you're using an XPATH. Personally I like to use `By.CSS_SELECTOR` but to each their own. Pick one and I believe you can get the value from the element using one of these two ways:

Example given with XPATH since you're using an XPATH.

```
elem2=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='description']").text
```

Or you can try:

```
elem2=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='description']")
elem2.get_attribute("value")
```

You may also need to wait for the element to actually be in the DOM to get the text/value. You can use [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) to wait for the element to either be in the DOM or be in the DOM and visible.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

[image: error]

...implies that [*`InvalidSelectorException`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71086380/7429447) was raised as an ***invalid*** / ***illegal*** selector was supplied.

---

### This usecase

In the line:

```
elem2=driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"//div[@class='description']")
```

though you mentioned about `By.CLASS_NAME` but in the *value* field you have passed a *xpath* value instead of a *classname*.

---

### Solution

You need to change the line of code in following either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *`By.CLASS_NAME`*:

  ```
  elem2 = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "description")
  ```
- Using *`By.XPATH`*:

  ```
  elem2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='description']")
  ```
- Using *`By.CSS_SELECTOR`*:

  ```
  elem2 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.description")
  ```

---

### Update

As per your question update these

[image: elements]

...are the elements printed to the console as per the line of code:

```
print(elem2)
```

Looking at the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) for the [website](https://www.casinoimportaciones.com.uy/accesorios-escola#/pageSize=8&viewMode=grid&orderBy=0) possibly you are looking for the product description and in that case you can use either of the following solutions:

- Using *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(elem2.text)
  ```
- Using *`get_attribute("textContent")`*:

  ```
  print(elem2.get_attribute("textContent"))
  ```
- Using *`get_attribute("innerHTML")`*:

  ```
  print(elem2.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```